# Developing a spring boot application with docker on windows but run the docker container on a Ubuntu VM (as Docker Host)

Tags: spring, ubuntu, docker, intellij-idea, virtual-machine

I want to develope a sample spring boot application with **Spring Boot**, **Docker** and my **IntelliJ IDE**. My operating system is Windows 10 but I do not want to use docker on windows.

Can anybody describe me a possible workflow where I can develope my application on windows 10 and run the image on the ubuntu vm? I read about defining the virtual machine as docker host and forwarding the container on my system to it and execute them there? Kind of a local deployment.

Ideas how to do it fairly easily and not to complex?

@Anunay actually described what I want on point. I'd love to see a practical guide to this approach like what docker features may be used for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow is pretty easy:

1. Place a Dockerfile in your project directory.
2. Now use docker-machine on your local Windows 10 system to start a Docker host. Docker-machine supports local deployment and cloud deployment of a docker host to many major cloud providers.
3. Tell docker-machine with `docker-machine env yourmachine` to create the connection credentials locally. -> Now your Docker commands are relayed to the Docker host.
4. Now configure your build system (e.g. maven) to build a Docker image after the spring-boot all-in-one-jar has been built. (deployment phase or integration-test-pre-phase). -> The image will be avaiable on your Docker host.
5. Start the container on the Docker host from your built image.
6. Run integration tests and have fun.

Note:

- The usual default operating system of the Docker host is Ubuntu.

Comment: So I can  `docker-machine env` to my local vm running an ubuntu image?

Comment: docker-machine creates by default a local virtualbox vm with a ubuntu image. You can also start a machine in any cloud or choose different images. The `env` command does only work on machines created by docker-machine.

Comment: As an alternative you can configure your own vm Docker host to accept remote connections. Then locally set the env $DOCKER_HOST pointing to your vm without docker-machine

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to run spring boot app in docker, just get a docker for java and create your own dockerfile by copying the jars and exposing the port.
All you really need is jre (as you can run just a jar)

But if you really want everything from ubuntu base you can check this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/dordoka/tomcat/~/dockerfile/)

Here is a sample.

```
FROM dordoka/tomcat    
ADD ROOT.war /    
ADD ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx2272m'
RUN chmod +x /my-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/my-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

my-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash    
/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

Comment: What I want is to develop on my IntelliJ IDE on **Windows 10** but run the developed application incl. docker image on my **Ubuntu VM**. The main reason is that I have to way of installing docker on windows nor I want to install it there. I simply want to develope on windows and run the docker image on my ubuntu vm

Comment: In that case I can suggest you to look into remote docker apis. Idea is to write your code in windows, create docker images after build, and invoke docker remotely to fetch the latest image and deploy it for you to debug further. If uploading to hub is an issue you can share the source code or the jar to the VM and ask docker to start with new version each time you want to build. You should be even be able to do a remote debug. I have never done this but should be similar to [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/docker-support-in-intellij-idea-14-1/) plugin

Comment: exactly what I want. Would be awesome if somebody could describe me some practical steps and features of docker that allow this!

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your application on windows 10 by using IntelliJ IDE. After you complete development, you can take your production to create image in ubuntu. By doing this it is easy and not complicated as creating docker image on window system.

Comment: Ah ok - so after I have a certain state I can pack it into a docker image. Well sure that's a way. But people sometimes tell me that I should start developing with docker right from scratch? What about that?

Comment: Docker is a tool designed to make it easier to create, deploy, and run applications by using containers. And Springboot with Docker also need many configuration, so if possible you should start developing your springboot application right from scratch with Docker.
Please view here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit old questions but may be helpful for others :)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/springbootsrv.jar springbootsrv.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "springbootsrv.jar"]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootsrv</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>springbootsrv</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**SpringBootApp.java**

```
package com.test.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.boot")
public class SpringBootApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

**SpringController.java**

```
package com.test.boot.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.boot.models.User;

@RestController
public class SpringController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String welcome() {
    return "Welcome to Spring Boot Tutorials";
  }

  @GetMapping("/user")
  public Map<String,User> myData() {
    User u = new User();
    u.setUserName("prasobh");
    u.setPassword("*****");
    Map a = new HashMap<String,User>();
    a.put("1", u);
    return a;
  }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.test.boot.models;

public class User {
  private String userName;
  private String password;

  public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }


}
```

**Docker Commands:**

```
#Load project docker image
docker build -f Dockerfile -t springbootsrv .
#Run project
docker run -p 8080:8080 springbootsrv
#Save docker image to system for share to team
docker save -o springbootsrv.tar springbootsrv
#load docker image to docker
docker load -i springbootsrv.tar
#List all images
docker images -a
#stop image 
docker stop (image id)
#delete image  (image id)
docker rmi -f b215037a9987
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

[image]